# UPC Database Lookup with developer Key using Ruby XMLRPC

Tags: ruby, database, xml-rpc, lookup

**What's wrong with this code?**

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'
def find_product(key, upc)
  server = XMLRPC::Client.new2('http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc')
  begin
    response = server.call('lookup',[{'rpc_key' => key}, {'upc' =>upc}] )
    rescue XMLRPC::FaultException => e
    puts "Error: "
    puts e.faultCode
    puts e.faultString
  end
end
dev_key  = '40bf22cb32833a2af48fd65121128fc28e42d580'
upc_code = '099482409463'
puts find_product(dev_key, upc_code)
```

### Response from UPCdatabase

```
{"status"=>"fail", "message"=>"Invalid parameters"}
```

I am not able to find out, which parameter is invalid, as there is not much information available on http://www.upcdatabase.com/ about their API.

Can anyone help me? I am using Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: <snark>What's wrong with it -- you mean other than the fact that you're using XML-RPC? :)</snark>

Comment: Also, you're rescuing an exception. What does that exception have to say for itself?

Answer (score 2):

That is so funny that I was just banging my head on the same thing. This code works for me:

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'
server = XMLRPC::Client.new("www.upcdatabase.com", "/xmlrpc")
result = server.call("lookup", 'rpc_key' => "mykey", 'upc' => "071160055506")
```

Edit: I also found http://www.upcdatabase.org/api.php which has actually a json api, I will give that a try also and post back if you would like.

Comment: I think they've updated their API, so the code above no longer works. Could be wrong...